# If $Ax=c(x)e, \forall x$, then $A$ has rank one

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

How to prove if $Ax=c(x)e, \forall x$, then $A$ has rank one?

1. $e$ is a vector with all entries one.
2. $c(x)\in \mathbb{R}$, which is a constant depending on $x$

---

My method is by Gaussian Elimination:

$[A\ \ | \ c(x)e] \rightarrow [A_1\ \ | \ \ $$\begin{bmatrix}c(x) \\0 \\0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$ \ \ ]$.

So can I say $A$ has rank one by this?

Comment: I would simply note that $\dim\operatorname{im}A=1$.

Comment: I’m not sure that what you have is quite enough. How do you know that the rows of $A_1$ that correspond to the zeros on the rhs are themselves zero? You need $\dim\ker A=n-1$, so there can’t be pivots anywhere besides the first row.

Comment: no  the rhs is after gaussian elimination of $c(x)e$, $e$ is a vector of all entries one. I do not have to know what $A_1$ is. $A_1$ is just the matrix after gaussian elimination of  $A$.

Comment: So, you’ve subtracted the first row of $A$ from every other row. How do you know that this set all of those rows to $0$ (equivalently, that the rows of $A$ were all equal) which is what you’d need for a rank of $1$.

Comment: Not quite. Rows of $A$ are just collinear. If $A$ is stochastic matrix, then since sum of entries of row equal to one, then I can say rows of $A$ are identical.

Comment: You’ve provided no justification for believing that either of those things is true. You have to say something about what the rows of $A_1$ are after this operation to be able to conclude anything from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank is the dimension of the range, i.e. of the set of all vectors $Ax$.  Those vectors are all multiples of $e$, so the rank is **at most** $1$.  It would be $0$ if all $c(x) = 0$, otherwise it is $1$.

Comment: Thanks!!  I almost forget this property.